# Rails "Warden::Proxy" error when trying to determine 'current_user' in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I have a simple live chat app and a messages controller:

```
 class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def create
   @message = current_user.messages.create(body: msg_params[:body], room_id: params[:room_id])
  end

  private

  def msg_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

And for my live chat I'm trying to create a visible difference between messages sent by "current_user" and other messages, you can see it in this views:
_message.html.erb

```
<div class="cont-<%=message.user.id%>">
  <div class="message-box msg-<%= message.user.id %> <%= current_user == message.user ? 'my_msg' : 'usr_msg'%>">
    <% unless message.room.is_private %>
      <h6 class="name"> <%= message.user.email %> </h6>
    <% end %>
    <%= message.body %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did it through comparing of message.user and current_user and depending of results div will receive different class ("my_msg" or "usr_msg"). It works fine while rendering but whenever I'm trying to create new message I receive this error:

```
 Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment.
Make sure that your application is loading Devise and Warden as expected and that the `Warden::Manager` middleware is present in your middleware stack.
If you are seeing this on one of your tests, ensure that your tests are either executing the Rails middleware stack or that your tests are using the `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` module to inject the `request.env['warden']` object for you.
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: Hi I seem to have a very similar problem. Have you figured out what the issue might be?